# Only navigator is working inside onTap() of Inkwell

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am listing out notifications. I want to update read status in database when the user clicked on the notification. I used the update function inside the OnTap() function of Inkwell widget, along with navigation to next page. But the async function is not calling. Is there any possible way to solve this issue?

Here is my Code :

```
class NotificationList extends StatefulWidget {
const NotificationList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
 _NotificationListState createState() => _NotificationListState();
 }

class _NotificationListState extends State<NotificationList> {
 String useremail = '';
 String appusertype = '';

 Future getList() async {
 SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
  useremail = preferences.getString('useremail') ?? "Not found";

  //debugPrint(useremail);
  // debugPrint(appusertype);
  });

 Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Charset': 'utf-8'
 };
 Map<String, dynamic> body = {
  "email": useremail,
 };
 var bodyEncoded = body.keys.map((key) => "$key=${body[key]}").join("&");
 //print(bodyEncoded);
 var url = "/notification_list.php";
 var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiConstant.baseUrl + url),
    headers: headers,
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    body: bodyEncoded);
 
 return json.decode(response.body);
 }

Future updateStatus(id) async {
 Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Charset': 'utf-8'
};
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
  "id": id,
};
var bodyEncoded = body.keys.map((key) => "$key=${body[key]}").join("&");
//print(bodyEncoded);
var url = "/update_notification.php";
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiConstant.baseUrl + url),
    headers: headers,
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    body: bodyEncoded);
print(id);
print("object");
return jsonDecode(response.body);
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
// checkLogin();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 64, 122),
      title: const Text(
        'Notifications',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      bottom: const PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.zero,
          child: Text(
            "عرض قائمة الممتلكات",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
          )),
    ),
    body: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/building.jpg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getList(),
            builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              //print("object");
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List list = snapshot.data as List;
                if (list.isEmpty) {
                  return const Center(
                      child: Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: Text('No Notifications yet!'),
                          )));
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      List? list = snapshot.data as List?;
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          updateStatus(list![index]['id']);
                          print(list[index]['id']);

                          list[index]['title'] == "Interest Request"
                              ? Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const InterestRequestList()))
                              : null;
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                // Container(
                                //   width: 50,
                                //   height: 70,
                                // decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                //   image: DecorationImage(
                                //               image: AssetImage ("assets/building.jpg"),
                                //               fit:BoxFit.cover,
                                //               )
                                // ),),
                                const Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.notifications,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                //Spacer(),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 5,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        10, 0, 0, 0),
                                    child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          list![index]['read_status'] == '0'
                                              ? Text(
                                                  list[index]['title'],
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                                      fontSize: 15),
                                                )
                                              : Text(
                                                  list[index]['title'],
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                                      fontSize: 15),
                                                ),
                                          Text(list[index]['body']),
                                        ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                //const Spacer(),

                                const Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }));
              }
              return const Center(
                  child: Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Text('No Notifications yet!'),
                      )));
              // else {
              //   return const Center(
              //     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              //   );
              // }
            }),
          )),
    ));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `await` in front of `updateStatus` call.

```dart
await updateStatus(list![index]['id']);
```

Comment: i used it , but still it doesn't work.